# how to set up document sets by default

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set

I have a customer that has the following needs:

He uses document sets in a document library, but he also wants the same document set to appear automatically when creating a new document library.
I've tried to show him how he acvtivates and adds document set to the library, but still he wants this automated.

The customer is a Office365 user.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. By design that SharePoint libraries only have one content type. You have to activate the site collection document sets feature first, then add the document set content type to the library manually.

A possible workaround is creating a library and add document set content type to the library. Then save this library as a template. Thus you could use that template to create library, this would add the document set.